# Oblique form of the word you

Tags: grammar

is the word 'you' used in its oblique form in this sentence?

"You, my creator, abhor me"

If not, could someone please identify the function of the word you in this instance.

Thanks!

(please pardon my ignorance if I've muddled terms here/completely off the mark, I'm not a seasoned linguist!)

Comment: `You` is the subject?!

Comment: What do you mean to say by "oblique form?"

Comment: What @John said. This is Too Basic.

Comment: What @Kris said. The question is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

"you" in "You abhor me" is the normal subject case or nominative. "my creator" is an apposition to "you". I don't know where you got the term oblique case from, but this term is not used in English grammar, instead of nominative, genitive, dative and accusative English grammars use the terms subject case, possessive case, indirect object and direct object.

Sometimes the terms straight cases are used for nominative and accusative, oblique cases are the other cases. There are other definitions of oblique cases as well. But I think you can forget the term oblique case, it plays no role in English grammar.

Comment: Yes: the two constructions _Brigadier Gerard, the racehorse, was there.'_ and 'I showed Brigadier Gerard the racehorse.' are very different beasts.

Comment: is "obligue" a typo ?